# Java tournament bracket

Tags: java, jframe

I'm working on a java application which requires the creation of a tournament bracket to take in event results, and I would like to display this tournament in a JFrame if possible, it needs to show 2,4,8,16, etc original players. I want to dynamically generate this using a jcombobox to ask the user how many players they want in the event and then have the appropriate number (and hopefully appropriately spaced) of jtextboxes.

Any ideas on an "easy" way to go about coding this myself? Not looking for complete code, just a starting point.

Edit: When I get around to finishing up code for this project, I'll post the layout I've done here for everyone's future reference.

Comment: Are you planning on using Swing components? Or use graphics?

Comment: Swing components was the plan

Comment: What do you have so far? You could create new JLabels for each of the players and position them appropriately.

Comment: I'm still in brainstorming for this. The best idea I had come across so far was to use the panel's width to arrange JTextFields/JLabels with players names (and they'd have an action associated with clicking them in case of a win), and use the panel's height to spread them out equally across the pane, but I was looking for any simpler solutions than that. I'd love to connect the labels with lines, but other than using separators (Which would be a pain), I can't fathom this out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, but you could arrange the players names like this:

```
Player 1         Player 2          Player 3
Player 2
Player 3         Player 3
Player 4
```

If you have to have the lines, you'll have to draw the diagram on a JPanel, and have another JPanel for data entry.

Comment: That was one solution I looked at. That would be somewhat simpler to implement than a graph from both sides, but unfortunately somewhat less aesthetically pleasing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a `JPanel` that has a `GridLayout` with a single row.  In each slot of the `GridLayout`, you have another `JPanel`.  These `JPanel` instance are also managed by a `GridLayout`, but in these panels, they hold a single column of `JPanel`s.  Each of these internal `JPanel` instances would hold your `JTextField`s.

Comment: Interesting idea, though managing all of those JPanels seems like an overly complex solution, just becoming bloated. Say with 32 players, you would have 1 for the main, 9 columns (16 from each side), and 32 rows, making for 42 JPanels. Nice idea though.